# github search api can't find language:C++

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using this api: `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=language:C++`
to find C++ repositories.

But the return page is all `language:C`, Why?

Comment: use `cpp` instead of `c++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets keep aside about searching a repositories using API's for moment to understanding the expected results

When you search the `C++` from [github search engine](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=c%2B%2B) then you will find very less amount of `C++` repositories were `C` repositories also fetched.

But when you search for `cpp` from [github search engine](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cpp) then you will get 95% of `C++` repositories.

So same will work for `API's`. I tested same by API and got expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Literal "+" signs in a URL after a "?" query customarily get replaced by SPACE characters.  So this would normally get interpreted as "c  ".  In order to transmit "c++" after a "?", it is safest to type "c%2B%2B".